# Wait for action to finish before showing a modal?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm stuck with a modal, I need my method (new_favorite) to finish executing so that within the modal I can use the session hash, but the partial is being rendered before the session object is updated. This is what i have so far.

```
#index.html.erb
<% @outstanding_cars.each_with_index do |car, index| %>
  ...
  <%= button_to "ADD FAVORITE", {controller: 'home', action: 'new_favorite', favorite_car_id: car.id}, remote: true, data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#favorite_modal'} %>
  <div id='favorite_modal' class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
    <%= render partial: 'layouts/new' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

#home_controller.rb
  def new_favorite
    if !session[:favorites_ids].present?
      session[:favorites_ids] = []
    end
    if session[:favorites_ids].length < 3
      session[:favorites_ids] << params[:favorite_car_id]
      session[:favorite_added]= true
    else
      session[:favorite_added] = false
    end
  end

#_new.html.erb
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button title="Cerrar" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <% if session[:favorite_added] %>
        <p>
          Added!
        </p>
      <% else %>
        <p>
          Enough cars for now, buddy.
        </p>
      <% end %>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are adding an element with ID 'favorite_modal' on each outstanding_cars iteration, you'll have multiple elements with the same ID which is not right.

You should render the modal as a view of the `new_favorite` action instead of prerendering the modal on the index view.

So, remove that `render 'layouts/new'` line and do something like:

```
#at views/home/new_favorite.js.erb
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<%= j render partial: 'layouts/new_modal' %>');
$('#favorite_modal').modal('toggle');
```

Remove the modal DIV from the loop and append the complete HTML not just the content of the modal.

```
#at views/layouts/_new_modal.html.erb
<div id='favorite_modal' class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <%= render partial: 'layouts/new' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some js to update the partial with new session after going in the controller and also move the code to trigger the modal to the js after updation of the partial. 
Also, you need to keep the modal div outside the 'outstanding_cars' loop so that we have only one div to update instead of one div for each car (credit to @arieljuod, noticed it only after his answer):

```
#index.html.erb
<% @outstanding_cars.each_with_index do |car, index| %>
  ...
  <%= button_to "ADD FAVORITE", {controller: 'home', action: 'new_favorite', favorite_car_id: car.id}, remote: true} %>
<% end %>

<div id='favorite_modal' class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  ...
  <%= render partial: 'layouts/new' %>
</div>

#home_controller.rb
  def new_favorite
    session[:favorite_added] = false
    session[:favourite_ids] ||= []
    if session[:favorites_ids].length < 3
      session[:favorites_ids] << params[:favorite_car_id]
      session[:favorite_added] = true
    end
  end

# app/views/home/new_favorite.js.erb
$('#favorite_modal').html("<%= j render partial: 'layouts/new' %>");
$('#favorite_modal').modal('toggle');
```

The code `j` is an alias for [escape_javascript](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) which escapes quotes and other stuff from the html that rails partail return.